# FPDF - PHP - Different styles on center cell

Tags: php, fpdf

My problem is that I have a center text in a cell and I want the word "Client:" in bold and the rest in regular, like is centered I cant print "client:" first and after that print the name, neither use "write" function because is centered, please help.

```
    $pdf->SetTextColor(102, 106, 117);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);
    $pdf->Cell(626,25,"Client: ".$name,0,0,'C',0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to calculate position of centered text like follows:

```php
require("fpdf.php");

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetTextColor(102, 106, 117);
$fullCellWidth = $pdf->GetPageWidth();

$pdf->SetFont("Arial", "", 15);
$regularCell = "some name";
$regularWidth = $pdf->GetStringWidth($regularCell);

$pdf->SetFont("Arial", "B", 15);
$boldCell = "Client: ";
$boldWidth = $pdf->GetStringWidth($boldCell);

$centerIndentX = ($fullCellWidth - $boldWidth - $regularWidth) / 2;

$pdf->SetX($centerIndentX);
$pdf->Cell($boldWidth, 25, $boldCell, 0, 0, "L");

$pdf->SetX($centerIndentX + $boldWidth);
$pdf->SetFont("Arial", "", 15);
$pdf->Cell($regularWidth, 25, $regularCell, 0, 0, "L");

$pdf->Output();
```

**The output PDF example - part of screenshot:**

[image]